# Filter data in state level vs multiple api calls. Which one is best practice?

Tags: reactjs

I have data in the state. I want to filter based on few things, do I need to filter data in state or call multiple API calls to backend?
which one is better?

Comment: do you use redux-saga ? https://redux-saga.js.org

Comment: no...at present we are not using

Comment: well then, I would just bring the data from state to the component and filter it there, there are better ways to handle data but from the info you provided, this is what I would have done,  don't make lots of API calls to server just for processing data  this is something to avoid doing in any case

Answer (score 0):

I would say it really depends on your data, the amount of it and the use you are making of it.

But anyway, the best practice is to be sure that each call to your API is actually providing already sorted data, without any parasite metadata.

So it's really a backend job in the DB query when it's about sorting or populating some fields.